How to query a Snowpark dataframe, with SQL, from Snowflake?
I have a Snowpark dataframe, that I would like to query (and join to other tables) using SQL.
The Snowpark dataframe is created in a Python cell.
I would like to query it in a SQL cell.  If the Snowpark dataframe is called mydf, how do I refer to it in SQL?
Thank you!

I don't think there is a way to directly reference the dataframe in your SQL yet.
But you can create a temporary view from your dataframe, and then query that directly from your SQL.
For example :
# Python cell
ts_df = session.sql('select current_timestamp()')
ts_df.create_or_replace_view('ts_temp_view')

-- SQL Cell
select * from 'ts_temp_view';

You could also do something like this if you want to define the view name as a variable programmatically, and then use it via a parameter in your SQL.
# Python cell
view_name = 'ts_temp_view'
ts_df = session.sql('select current_timestamp()')
ts_df.create_or_replace_view(view_name)

-- SQL Cell
select * from {{view_name}};


Thank you so much Fieldy, that worked perfectly!!!
